# How to double the spacing of certain number of lines in a file using sed

Tags: sed

I need to double the spacing for a certain number of lines in all the files in a folder. 
I need to know the command for the same. 
For doubling the number of lines of one whole file I used the command:

```
sed '/^$/d' fileName | sed G
```

1. I need to know how to do this for only specific number of lines
2. I want to make the change in all the files in the folder structure

Comment: Without samples of input and expected output it is very difficult for us, please do add samples of input and expected output in your question and let us know then.

Comment: Hi, I tried to give the sample input and output , but the formatting doesnt allow me double spacing between lines.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU find,sed and parallel):

```
find -type f | parallel --dry-run -q sed -Ezi 's/\n+/\n/g;s/\n/&&/10g;s/\n+/\n/21g'
```

This will double space lines 10-20 for all files in current directory and below (but only after the commands to do this have be checked by the user and the `--dry-run` removed).

An alternative, less efficient:

```
find -type f | parallel --dry 'sed -i "/\S/!d" {} ; sed -i "10,20G" {}'
```

Comment: Could you please explain the part after pipe.

Comment: @dfordevy see [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) for GNU parallel and [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html) for a tutorial.